# binance cancel order request sends back 'unknown unorder received'

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client, python-binance

I'm using the binance connector API with python https://binance-connector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ with the testnet (https://testnet.binance.vision/) to build a trading bot.

**The problem that I have is** that I'm sending a request to cancel an order on a certain symbol and I get back 'unknown order received'.

***This is the log:***

```
    'rateLimits': [   {   'count': 17,
                          'interval': 'MINUTE',
                          'intervalNum': 1,
                          'limit': 6000,
                          'rateLimitType': 'REQUEST_WEIGHT'}],
    'result': {   'clientOrderId': 'ECryC5RymE2cD4u50P11HI',
                  'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000',
                  'executedQty': '0.00000000',
                  'icebergQty': '0.00000000',
                  'isWorking': True,
                  'orderId': 12264945,
                  'orderListId': -1,
                  'origQty': '0.00054600',
                  'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000',
                  'price': '27449.33000000',
                  'selfTradePreventionMode': 'NONE',
                  'side': 'BUY',
                  'status': 'NEW',
                  'stopPrice': '0.00000000',
                  'symbol': 'BTCUSDT',
                  'time': 1696284008962,
                  'timeInForce': 'GTC',
                  'type': 'LIMIT',
                  'updateTime': 1696284008962,
                  'workingTime': 1696284008962},
    'status': 200}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-10-02 22:00:11.073 UTC DEBUG binance.websocket.websocket_client: Sending message to Binance WebSocket Server: {"id": "48b42ef9-6e14-467c-b35c-7f6e52de514c", "method": "depth", "params": {"symbol": "BTCUSDT", "limit": 1}}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{   'id': '48b42ef9-6e14-467c-b35c-7f6e52de514c',
    'rateLimits': [   {   'count': 19,
                          'interval': 'MINUTE',
                          'intervalNum': 1,
                          'limit': 6000,
                          'rateLimitType': 'REQUEST_WEIGHT'}],
    'result': {   'asks': [['27447.71000000', '0.02714400']],
                  'bids': [['27447.70000000', '0.03461200']],
                  'lastUpdateId': 20964071},
    'status': 200}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-10-02 22:00:11.307 UTC DEBUG binance.websocket.websocket_client: Sending message to Binance WebSocket Server: {"id": "f6ab36b1-3618-4061-bedd-d1046a3ee52a", "method": "order.cancel", "params": {"apiKey": "5aBdL8xhcEukeAqemVb5H0JSTXpAPYrX07BcHGw0WAjvJS4kClsLvT7rGkgyYsqA", "orderId": 12264945, "symbol": "BTCUSDT", "timestamp": 1696284011307, "signature": "cabf41556cd22cf6af425729a9e77a042d3a77958c5d8118922bc67f1546957c"}}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{   'error': {'code': -2011, 'msg': 'Unknown order sent.'},
    'id': 'f6ab36b1-3618-4061-bedd-d1046a3ee52a',
    'rateLimits': [   {   'count': 20,
                          'interval': 'MINUTE',
                          'intervalNum': 1,
                          'limit': 6000,
                          'rateLimitType': 'REQUEST_WEIGHT'}],
    'status': 400}
```

This is the code for the cancel order:

```py
    def cancel_order(self, id: int) -> None:
        self.currently_cancelling_order = True
        self.binance_api_client.cancel_order(
            symbol=self.TRADING_SYMBOL,
            orderId=id,
        )
```

The id for the order I'm trying to cancel is always correct, no matter what, you can check this in the log file as well.

This is **the documentation for the request to cancel:** https://binance-connector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.spot.trade.html?order#binance.spot.trade.cancel_order.

**I think** it's possible that my order might have gotten filled somewhere during the process and when I'm trying to cancel it, I can't cancel it anymore, so I get this answer back.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: the reasons for this error could be:

1)  Order is not found, like wrong order id
2)  Order is found, but it's not available to cancel. e.g. filled, cancelled, expired, partial filled, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error because I was trying to cancel an order that has gotten filled.